# Linux в роли роутера

Tags: iptables, linux

Имеется задача.

Есть 3 группы пользователей:

> 1. Бухгалтерия.  192.168.0.1-10
> 2. Ещё кто-то. 192.168.0.11-20
> 3. Администраторы.  192.168.0.21-30

- Первой группе надо заблокировать доступ в ВКонтакт, Одноклассники,.. торрент.
- Второй группе то же самое, только ещё и ICQ и прочие жаббер клиенты.
- Третьей группе не надо блокировать ничего.

Также желательно для каждого пользователя иметь логи посещения сайтов или лучше видеть активные подключения.

Как это можно реализовать? И можно ли это вообще сделать, используя только **IPTABLES**?
Или надо ещё какой-то прокси сервер использовать?

Уточню: 2 сетевые карты; первая - интернет, вторая - в свитч.

Comment: Эти все ограничения легко обходятся с помощью внешних прокси серверов, руководству лучше поработать над мотивацией персонала.

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать используя только iptables.
На вопрос "как?", ответите сами, пройдя по [ссылочке](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/)
Необходимо добавить правила в цепочку [FORWARD](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/#FORWARDCHAIN). Там же можно использовать ключи [LOG](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/#LOGTARGET) или [ULOG](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/#ULOGTARGET) (для ULOG необходимо будет установить дополнительное ПО, но это просто, причем у него больше вариантов (например запись в MySQL), а потом легко отчеты делать для начальства).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите решить задачу как можно быстрее - поставьте Endian Firewall Community.
Это продукт на основе CentOS с очень удобным веб-интерфейсом. Создавать там правила очень удобно, можно настроить логи по AD пользователям. Насколько я понимаю раз в CentOS стандартно IPTables то и это решение должно быть на нем.

Answer (score 1):

Готовые продукты:
IPFire http://www.ipfire.org/ на базе Linux
pfSense https://www.pfsense.org/ на базе FreeBSD